# Rewriting HTML with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my Javascript application, I receive a line of HTML code from an endpoint. I cannot change the HTML content that I receive from this endpoint. I want to convert the radio buttons into a regular button, and not sure how to go about rewriting this. The HTML I receive can have anything in it - I only want to replace the radio buttons.

Here's what I might be given as a string:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="1">Option 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="2">Option 2
</form>
```

and I want to convert it to this string:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" id="button-a-1" value="Option 1">
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="button-a-2" value="Option 2">
</form>
```

Here's how this is currently used:

```
$.post('url', data, function(resp) { $('#content').html(resp.html); });
```

I thought I could do this by find/replace type="radio" with type="button", but I'm not sure how to get the text after the input tag into a value tag by manipulating the string. And also get an id in there so I can tie an event handler to it.

Comment: `Option 1` part is what makes this a pain.... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the text node which is immediately after the radio, then generate the button based on the textnode content and replace the radio button with genrated button.

```js
let html = `<form>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="1">Option 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="2">Option 2
</form>`;

// create jQuery object from html content
let $html = $(html);

$html
// filter out all the radio buttons
.find(':radio')
// use replaceWith to iterate and replace with returned element
.replaceWith(function() {
// get the text node which is immediately after the radio
  let textNode = this.nextSibling;
  // get its textcontent
  this.value =
  // remove text node
    textNode.remove();
    // generate button and return
  return $('<input>', {
    type: 'button',
    id: `button-${this.name}-${this.value}`,
    value: textNode.nodeValue.trim()
  })
})

$('#content').html($html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

---

Or alternately you can modify the existing `input` element without creating new.

```js
let html = `<form>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="1">Option 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="2">Option 2
</form>`;

// create jQuery object from html content
let $html = $(html);

$html
  // filter out all the radio buttons
  .find(':radio')
  // iterate and update the element
  .each(function() {
    // get the text node which is immediately after the radio
    let textNode = this.nextSibling;
    // get its textcontent
    this.value =
      // remove text node
      textNode.remove();

    // change properties

    this.type = 'button';
    this.id = `button-${this.name}-${this.value}`;
    this.value = textNode.nodeValue.trim();

  })

$('#content').html($html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: I implemented this approach and it's working! How would I go about assigning a click event handler to this new button?

Comment: @GregSenne : `$('<input>', { ....  }).click(function(){ /*your handler code here */ })`

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to do it with the DOM and not working with the strings. Create it as a fragement, select the elements, and replace them.

```js
const responseText = `
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="1">Option 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="2">Option 2
</form>
`
// create temp element and set the html to it
var temp = document.createElement('div')
temp.innerHTML = responseText
// find the radio buttons
var radios = temp.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
// loop over each one so we can convert it
radios.forEach(function (rb) {
  // create a button
  const button = document.createElement('input')
  button.type = 'button'
  // set the id with the radio button attributes
  button.id = `button-${rb.name}-${rb.value}` // = `button-' + rb.name + '-' + rb.value'
  // read the next sibling's text and set the value to 
  button.value = rb.nextSibling.nodeValue.trim()
  // remove the text node
  rb.nextSibling.remove()
  // replace the radio button with your new button
  rb.replaceWith(button)
});

console.log(temp.innerHTML)
```

Comment: mine is easier :)

Comment: Do you want a cookie @G.aziz??? And what you did probably will fail with real world data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that using only `javascript`

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

inputs.forEach((input, index) => {

  input.setAttribute("type", "button")
  input.setAttribute("value", `option ${index +1}`)
  input.setAttribute("id", `button-${input.getAttribute("name")}-${index+1}`)

})

form.innerHTML = form.innerHTML.replace(/Option\s[1-9]/g, "")

console.log(form.innerHTML)
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="1">Option 1
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="2">Option 2
</form>
```

Comment: and what about the id and the value:?

Comment: sorry what are you talking about ?

Comment: `<input type="button" id="button-a-1" value="Option 1">` is supposed to be the final outcome. Your solution is not close. `<input type="button" name="a" value="1">`

Answer (score 0):

use the jQuery [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)  function

```js
$("input").attr('type', 'button');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="1">Option 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="2">Option 2
</form>
```

Comment: and what about the id and the value:?